# Cant install chrome - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: google-chrome

I am Linux newbie. I installed Ubuntu today, and I don't know how to install Google Chrome browser. I first downloaded it from official page. After opening it, clicking install and entering password, it stays jammed at "Installing". I tried it multiple times, and now the whole "Ubuntu Software" app is jammed - it shows only main page, but when I want to find something or go to "Installed" or "Updates" tab, there is just loading circle...

```
sudo apt-get -f install output:  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.  
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1  
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1  
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1  
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1  
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1  
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
```

Comment: Could you try to execute this in the terminal and give me the output? `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1

Comment: W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1

Comment: W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list:1

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the output.

Comment: What's happening is that you've tried it so many times that it has created a lot of duplicates. The easiest way to fix this is to reinstall the operating system, seeing as you've only recently installed Ubuntu. If you don't want to do this I, or someone else can help you along the process of getting rid of those duplicates.

Comment: Thank you, I try reinstalling, I will let you know how it gone then.

Comment: Good luck! By the way, here is the preferred way of installing chrome on Ubuntu 16.04: http://www.ubuntumaniac.com/2016/04/install-google-chrome-50-on-ubuntu-1604.html

Comment: You dont need to reinstall ... you only have to edit the files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d you will see google-chrome.list if you only see the list once then open it and you will probably see the source in there 3 times .. just remove the duplicates or just delete the list all together and the errors will go away

Comment: I reinstalled, and now everything works fine, but good to know a way to do it without reinstall. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Ubuntu software centre, search for chromium and install it.
It will ask for password, provide password, and it will be installed.

Comment: I want Chrome, because I have all my bookmarks \ extensions synced with google account

Comment: chromium is open source version of chrome. Each and every feature is same and regarding your bookmark. Just login in chromium using your Google account you to synchronize in chrome, and your bookmark and password will be automatically.

Comment: Oh I didnt know that, but its OK right now because I managed to install Chrome